# Understanding addStateDidChangeListener firebase authentication

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

Hi I am new to firebase and want to confirm my understanding of an auth function.(addStateDidChangeListener)

A little background:

When the app is first launched, the app delegate is called first and then this sceneDelegate function is called. Now it will present a screen based on whether the user is signed in or not. If they are not signed up it will present them with my signin/signup screen (self.createHandleSignInOrSignUp()).

Now 2 questions:

1. After they sign up or sign in the app jumps back to this block of code inside `.addStateDidChangeListener`.

   This is because the auth state changes, right?
2. Also while the app is running you can sign out, and then this block of code is called.

   This is because this function is always 'listening' for auth state changes while the app is running?

The code below is my part of my SceneDelegate.swift file and the function I have questions about.

Thank you

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)

    window?.windowScene = windowScene

    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ auth, user in
        if (user != nil) {
            self.window!.rootViewController = self.createTabBar()
        }
        else {
            self.window!.rootViewController = self.createHandleSignInOrSignUp()
        }
    })

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The completion handler for your auth state change listener will be called each time the auth state changes. This typically happens asynchronously, for example when the user signs in or signs out.
2. The auth state listener remains active until you remove it, or until the app exits.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. A follow up to your answer on #2. In a production app would  I then need to use userdefaults to store the state of the the login status for the best user experience.?So for example if they update their phone the app would exit so it would sign them out, unless I had a userdefault storage key saying they were still logged in to their user?

Comment: Firebase already persists the user's authentication state, and restores it when the app restarts.

Comment: Will do. My reputation doesn't allow my upvote to be seen yet lol. I'm still a noobie